# Github Desktop reverted 2 times my first commit and my files are all deleted

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

I just created an repository in Github Desktop and I forget to put to ignore the node_modules so I decided to revert my inital commit but I don't know how github desktop revert 2 times my initial commit and all my files was deleted. Now I want to know if have any possibility to recover this files? ( I am on a Windows 10 and the files was just deleted )

Comment: if you know the commit hash it's most likely still there in your local repo. SO, you just need to put it back to the head

Comment: @bruceg Thanks a lot! I managed to recover my project!!!!!

Comment: I know I am late but it may help someone. If you didn't commit you can "Discard All Changes" from the changes tab it will restore your all files.